# Почему a[(a=b) [3]] равняется 1, если отсчёт начинается с 0го индекса, a[3] по идее должно быть равно 0 как и b[3]

Tags: java, массивы

```
class Test{
  public static void main(String[ ] args){
    int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    int[] b = {2, 3, 1, 0};
    System.out.println(a[ (a = b)[3] ]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
a [ (a = b)[3] ]

0. __temp = a        // { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
1. a = b             // { 2, 3, 1, 0 }
2. { 2, 3, 1, 0 }[3] // 0
3. __temp[0]         // 1
```

Тонкий момент - окончательное значение берется из первоначального массива `a` (`{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }`), хотя переменная `a` к этому времени уже ссылается на `{ 2, 3, 1, 0 }`.

Answer (score 3):

В фрагменте `(a = b)[3]` вы извлекается из массива b элемент с индексом 3. Его значение - 0.
Затем вы достаете из массива a элемент с индексом, который равен извлеченному ранее значению, то есть элемент с индексом 0. В массиве a элемент с таким индексом равен 1.